# Why does remove() consider my Entity an array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Why does Symfony not recognize my entity as an entity? As seen in #2 Symfony knows the class, and doctrine should too since it is able to find the News Entity.

```
 /**
 * 
 * @Route("/news/delete/{id}", name="news_delete")
 */
public function deleteAction($id) {

    $toDelete = new News();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagers();

    $toDelete = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:News')
                ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

    dump($toDelete); //Posted under #1
    dump(get_class($toDelete)); //Posted under #2
    $em->remove($toDelete);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('news_show', array(), 301);
}



#1:   
News {#926 ▼
      -id: 16
      +headline: "1313"
      +newsBody: "12313"
      +date: DateTime {#1027 ▶}
      +archiveDate: DateTime {#921 ▶}
      -categories: PersistentCollection {#934 ▶}
    }

#2:
"AppBundle\Entity\News"
```

**EDIT:**
Error: Call to a member function remove() on array

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: @Emanuel Oster done.

Comment: The error message tells you, that `$em` is an array, not `$toDelete`. If you look closely, you will see, that you call `getManagers()` instead of `getManager()`

Comment: Thank you, I just did the same mistake again in my update controller.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the office it was pointed out to me that I called the getManagers() function, which returns an array with all the managers.

The rest of the code was also recomended to me for clarity.

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:News');
    $toDelete = $repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
```

Thank you to all those who took the time to start working on my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a tips, you can avoid magic call using find() function, since you are using only id

```
$toDelete = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:News')
            ->find($id);
```

Also, I also get problems about it, and solved it using `instanceof`

```
if($toDelete instanceof News)
{
    $em->remove($toDelete);
    $em->flush();
}
```